# Find path between two nodes in graph, according to given criteria - optimization task

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-theory, pseudocode, graph-traversal

I have the following problem. I have cyclic, undirected, weighted graph G=(V,E). I need to find the simple path (without cycles) between two given nodes according to these rules:

1. Finding minimal weight value in edges set of each possible path
2. Select this path, which has maximal min value among selected minimal values from found paths

E.g we have graph presented below:

[image: sample graph]

We can try to find simple path from node 1 to node 8. There are two possible pathes, listed below:

1. 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8, minimal edge weight on this path is 2
2. 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8, minimal edge weight on this path is 283

According to presented criteria, wanted path is path number 2, because it has greater minimal value, than path no 1.

One important assumption: the number of nodes in graph are very small: less than 15.

I thought about Dijkstra or Bellman-Ford algorithm modification, but the challenge is, that we don't have local criteria (the min distance) - we cannot find minimal weight of edge, until we don't obtain whole path...

My second think was to use modification of Nearest-Neighbor algorithm, but it's used for solving so called travelling salesman problem, which is a little different case comparing to mine.

**My question is following**. Is it better way to solve this problem, than use Depth-First Algorithm to obtain all direct acyclic simple paths between two given nodes and next select max value of min weight values of each found path?

In such case I'm a little worried about complexity of DFS algorithm, especially due to recursion and number of possible connections (edges) in graph.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: It looks like a [Widest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) or a "minimin" version of its minimax variation. It seems that there are quite efficient algorithms for them.

Comment: @julien - Thank you. It's even not a variation - "widest path problem" is exactly my problem, so it seems that I need to make maximum spanning tree from my graph and find the path from node A to node B in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on the minimal edge weight:

Assume your search interval is `[m, M]`. For a set value `L = (m + M) / 2`, use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to find a path from `source` to `destination` such that all edges have weight `>= L`. If you can do this, set `m = L + 1` and repeat the search. If you cannot do this, set `M = L - 1` and repeat the search.

This will be `O((edges + nodes) log maxEdgeWeight)`. Should be very fast for your small number of nodes.

Note that there is a way to do it without the log factor as well, by using the ideas of [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). But you definitely do not need this for so few nodes.

**Update 1:**

Here is how this would work on your example. First of all, your search interval will be `[2, 9000]`, since these are your min and max edge weights, respectively.

```
L = (2 + 9000) / 2 = 4501
=> Find a path from 1 to 8 such that all of its edges have weight >= 4501.
   This is not possible, so reduce the search interval to [2, 4500].

L = (2 + 4501) / 2 = 2251
=> Find a path from 1 to 8 such that all of its edges have weight >= 2251.
   This is not possible, reduce the search interval to [2, 2250]

L = (2 + 2250) / 2 = 1126
=> Not possible to find a path, reduce to [2, 1125]

L = (2 + 1125) / 2 = 563
=> Not possible, reduce to [2, 562]

L = (2 + 562) / 2 = 282
=> Success! We can find 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
Mark 282 as the current best answer, and keep searching in [283, 562].
```

Eventually, you will be left with `283` as the answer, which is what you want. Then just print any path with all edge weights `>= 283` (only one in your case).

Comment: I believe it's assumed that this is a simple scenario but he desires it to be useful when the graph scales. Otherwise he would not be worried about complexity at all.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - this method scales very well, and he did say "One important assumption: the number of nodes in graph are very small: less than 15.".

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - Thank you for your effort, but unfortunately I'm not sure if your solution goes me to my goal. I need to find min weight value among set of edges, which create found path from one node to other node. Next I need to find max value among set of previously fetched min values. So I would like to find global maximum among local minimums. If I correctly understand your solution, you propose to find global maximum weight using binary search algorithm, what is different from my assumptions... Could you write down example steps list of your algorithm in my sample graph case?

Comment: @Viper - I have added more info to my answer.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato Thanks. Now it looks more clearly, but I still have some doubts: 1) What is the stop condition of your algorithm? Take to consideration that in my graph is also the second path: 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8, which matches your condition (weights of all edges > 282) and you omitted it 2) What element are you looking for by making bisection? 3) Could you explain me, what is the guarantee of equality between my problem and your problem? Your solution is not naive case...

Comment: @Viper - this is my answer :P (IVlad). 1) You stop when `m > M` in your binary search. The last saved answer is your answer. Not sure what you mean by missing that path. My algorithm returns one such path. 2) I am looking for the largest value that fits your criteria. 3) Not sure what you mean. You want: for all paths from `s` to `t`, find the minimum value of their edges, then pick the path with the largest such minimum value. My algorithm binary searches for this.

Comment: @IVlad - Terribly sorry for my mistake - I'm a little tired last times. 1) IMHO you have lost fact, that in your step 5 there are two possible paths from node 1 to 8, where all weights have bigger value than 283: 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6-> 7-> 8 (you found it) AND path: 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 8 (weight with value "2" between nodes 5 and 8) - you don't listed this path...
Next, according to your stop condition (m > M) I should continue searching after your step 5, obtaining mentioned above two paths at each stage. Correct? <Continuation in next comment below>

Comment: 3) Yes, it looks, that you understand my problem correctly :) I'm trying to tell you in diplomatic way, that I don't understand mathematics background of your solution :) (as I told you before: you are looking for max weight directly, I expected two stages of solution: looking for min value, and next looking for max among min values)

Comment: @IVlad - Does your solution is equivalent to such solution from Wikipedia article, linked by Julien? "Based on this test, there also exists a linear time algorithm for finding a widest s-t path in an undirected graph, that does not use the maximum spanning tree. The main idea of the algorithm is to apply the linear-time path-finding algorithm to the median edge weight in the graph, and then either to delete all smaller edges or contract all larger edges according to whether a path does or does not exist, and recurse in the resulting smaller graph"

Comment: @Viper - 1) it doesn't matter how many paths there are, all you care about in the binary search stage is whether you can find an `s - t` path whose edges are all `>= L`. Once you have found the maximum weight with binary search, find a path whose edge weights are also >= what you've found (you can save this directly while binary searching). Yes, you should keep searching, I didn't list all the steps. No, my solution does not sound equivalent to that. The linear algorithm I mentioned would still depend on the edge weights, so it wouldn't really be linear, I guess.

Comment: @IVlad Thank you for your answer. Now, I think that I understand your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Find a maximum spanning tree (via the usual algorithms with the priority queue/sort order reversed) and take the unique path in it. The min edge on this path never would have been added to the tree if there were a path between its endpoints consisting of greater edges, as there would be if there were a better overall path.

Comment: (If it's just the one path, Prim's algorithm has a bidirectional variant by analogy with bidirectional Dijkstra.)