# The Widest Path Challenge - the most efficient way for finding path in Maximal Spanning Tree

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-traversal

This question is continuation of my similar earlier asked question: [Find path between two nodes in graph, according to given criteria - optimization task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468973/find-path-between-two-nodes-in-graph-according-to-given-criteria-optimization) .

**Problem summary**:
I need to find the best path in graph from vertex A to vertex B, with assumption, that path quality is calculated as min value of edge weight on path and next the best path is that, which has max min value. Generally it's so called ["Widest path problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem).

Previously I needed to solve this problem in very small graph (up to 15 vertices), so I didn't need sophisticated algorithm and with the help of kind peoples, I have designed my working algorithm. 
Unfortunately now *I need to redefine my necessities* in such way, that my graph can be very large (even 50 thousands of edges).
I'm aware that I need to find Maximal Spanning Tree for my graph and obtain a simple path from start to stop vertex in obtained MST.
I have decided to use [jGraphT](http://jgrapht.org) library. It has implemented [Kruskal Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/KruskalMinimumSpanningTree.html). I can obtain Maximal Spanning Tree by multiplying each edge weight by (-1) and using Kruskal for Minimal Spanning Tree, but algorithm in the library has been designed for retrieving Hash Set of MST edges.

**My question is following:**
I have obtained Maximal Spanning Tree of graph as java HashSet of edges. How I can find a path from vertex A to vertex B in such structure in the most efficient way and what data structure will be the most efficient for this purpose? What do you recommend me?

Additionally, I'm worried about such situation, that my graph is not always consistent (it may contain isolated vertices or isolated subgraphs), what is main condition for Kruskal algorithm correctness. Is it any way to bypass this problem?

Thank you for any help or tips.

Answer (score 1):

Use the set to construct a `Subgraph` object. Subclass `DepthFirstIterator` so that `encounterVertex` puts an entry with key `v` and value (whatever the other endpoint of `e` is) into a map `p`. Search depth-first from the sink. Recover the path by initializing `v` to be the source and looking up `v`, `p[v]`, `p[p[v]]`, etc., until there is no entry. This is a pain, but the library authors baked `FibonacciHeap` into `ClosestFirstIterator`, which otherwise would be the class you want. (Heck, if you don't care about another n log n time operation, you could just run Dijkstra on the subgraph.)

Kruskal's algorithm functions fine with disconnected graphs. It returns a minimum-weight spanning *forest*, i.e., for each connected component, a minimum-weight spanning tree. I can't vouch for this particular implementation.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I considered using of DepthFirstIterator class but I found it useless in my case due to impossibility of delivering start and stop vertices. I don't fully understand your solution. Especially how I can get your p map of adjacent vertices? encounterVertex() method is protected. The public  interface ensures only an access to Next() method, which retrieves new, visited vertex. Could you attach some piece of code? Thank you.